# how to place query out of while but us it in while?

Tags: php, mysql

i should show comment numbers in the post body. but the post body is in the while and if i place comments num query in while page while be to heavy!

what i'm trying to do but not working:

```
$comments_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `blogid`='$bid' AND `postid`='$postid'") or die(mysql_error());
$coments_num = mysql_num_rows($comments_data);

if($post_query) {
    while($post_data = mysql_fetch_array($post_query)) {
        $postid = $post_data['id'];
        $post_temp = $post;
        $post_temp = str_replace('[post_comments]',$coments_num,$post_temp);
        $posts .= $post_temp;
    }
}
```

but if i use like this will work:(but with to much queries!)

```
if($post_query) {
    while($post_data = mysql_fetch_array($post_query)) {
        $postid = $post_data['id'];
        $comments_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `blogid`='$bid' AND `postid`='$postid'") or die(mysql_error());
        $coments_num = mysql_num_rows($comments_data);
        $post_temp = $post;
        $post_temp = str_replace('[post_comments]',$coments_num,$post_temp);
        $posts .= $post_temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the number of comments in the post, and not the comments content. then use the [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) clause inside a join Query:

```
$post_query = "SELECT *, COUNT(comment.id) AS comment_num 
FROM post JOIN comment ON comment.post_id = post.id
GROUP BY post.id;"

if($post_query) {
  while($post_data = mysql_fetch_array($post_query)) {
    $postid = $post_data['id'];
    $comment_num = $post_data['comment_num'];
    $post_temp = $post;
    $posts .= $post_temp;
  }
}
```

**Check the [Working Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b5b7/5)**

Comment: my problem is here! the query is in the while! witch means there will be so many queries!

Comment: Just ujpdated my answer to use a join, check the demo

Comment: tnx, but i think u don't get it! the comments are in another table!

Comment: thats why I am using a join, did you see the Demo? there are 2 tables joined in the same query!

Answer (score 1):

On should *rarely* have to query the database from within a loop: it's often possible to construct a query that returns all of the desired results and then loop over that resultset—this will almost always improve performance.

Instead of fetching posts with one query, looping over that resultset and fetching each post's comments with another query, join your tables together; without knowing your schema or seeing the SQL for your `$post_query` it is impossible to be certain, but you probably want something like this:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     posts LEFT JOIN comments USING (postid)
WHERE    blogid = '$bid'
ORDER BY postid
```

Then loop over the results, detecting when you have encountered a new post by inspecting the `postid` column.

Comment: @user1968224 - why could you not use it? Some detail will probably help readers answer your questions.